# Какой тип цен, битрикс

Tags: битрикс, 1с

﻿Как должно быть ?  если производитель у товара один ,то и тип цен должен быть строго по этому производителю (например, поставщик ООО "ЕЕЕ", значит тип цен будет eee_zakup. У торговых предложении, если поставщик другой (он по идее другой), значит тип цен устанавливается именно для данного поставщика.﻿ Верно? и цен по другим поставщикам не должно быть.
﻿Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

В Битриксе с типами цен немного веселее. Если используется несколько типов цен, то нужно в настройках компонентов выводящих товаров выделить все типы цен, которые могут быть использованы. Если этого не сделать, то в Вашем случае некоторые товары останутся без цены. Типы цен, к сожалению общие для всех товаров. Но у каждого товара будут заполнены те типы цен, которые ему принадлежат.